# Filter using masks in n2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I'm using Angular 6 with [n2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/). I want to search a string with and without mask **on a filter**.

Ex.: `28871154000178` and `28.871.154/0001-78` should return the same data.

[image]

I looked around various forums but was unable to find such a way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using `filterFunction`.

Example:

```
columns: {
    column {
        title: 'CPF/CNPJ',
        filterFunction(cell?: any, search?: string) {
            const match = cell.indexOf(search) > -1;
            const matchClean = cell.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '').indexOf(search) > -1;
            return (match || search === '') ? true : (matchClean) ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```